# Invalid column name 'Length' webmatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

im new in asp.net mvc. i watch a tutorial and he is using webmatrix. i tried to add column named "IDViewer" in table "UserProfile" in my database created by webmatrix. but then, when i tried to insert some value it returns me an error of "Invalid column name 'Length'." but i did not declare column name "Length" in my code. please check my codes and the images. thank you

Images Link Here. please take a look

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nzjH.jpg)

[My database, i added column named IDViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJNvq.jpg)

```
public class Register
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 8 char long.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string IDViewer { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @style = "color: red" })
    <label>Username</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <label>Password</label>
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <label>Student ID</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IDViewer, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.DropDownList("role",roles,"Select Account Type")
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
}
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(Register registerdata, string role)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(registerdata.Username, registerdata.Password, registerdata.IDViewer);
            Roles.AddUserToRole(registerdata.Username,role);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry the username already exists");    
            return View(registerdata);
        }
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("","Data invalid");
    return View(registerdata);
}
```

Comment: The 3rd parameter needs to be a dictionary. Try replacing `registerdata.IDViewer` with `new { IDViewer = registerdata.IDViewer }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createuserandaccount(v=vs.111).aspx), the 3rd parameter is a dictionary

> propertyValues
>
> Type: System.Object
>
> (Optional) A dictionary that contains additional user attributes. The default is null.

so your method needs to be

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(registerdata.Username,
    registerdata.Password, new { IDViewer = registerdata.IDViewer });
```